# Get index from multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array like this:

```
var squares = new Array();
            for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                squares[i] = new Array();
                for(var j = (i * 20) + 1; j <= 20 * i + 20; j++)
                {
                    if (squares[i] == null)
                    {
                        squares[i] = ''+j;  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        squares[i].push('' + j);
                    }
                }
            }
```

I want to get the the index from the multidimensional array when I click on a square:

```
   angular.element('.click').click(function() {


            var squareId = angular.element(this).attr('id');                //Rutans id
            for(var k = 0; k <= 8; k++)
            {
                var squareIndex = squares[k].indexOf(squareId);
            }
            console.log(squareIndex);
```

But this only results in -1 by console.log. Anyone who can help me?

Comment: You're not doing anything with squareIndex during the loop. Its value after the loop is the value you got on the last iteration. Apparently, there's no squareId in your last array.

Comment: @Sacho: Thank you. But how can I get the value of squareId in my multidimensional array then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using indexOf() you are only checking that the ID exists within that array. So if it occurs in the first array, it will continue to loop over them return -1 overwriting the previous value.

What you need to do is stop the loop when you find it and return k, the index of the array you are currently iterating through.

Here is a fiddle, hope this helps
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chhxrq6a/3/)

```
var squares = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
    {
        squares[i] = new Array();
        for(var j = (i * 20) + 1; j <= 20 * i + 20; j++)
        {
            if (squares[i] == null)
            {
                squares[i] = ''+j;  
            }
            else
            {
                squares[i].push('' + j);
            }
        }
    }

console.log(squares);


$('a').on('click', function(){
var squareId = $(this).attr('id');
var squareIndex = 0,
    numberIndex = 0;

for(var k = 0; k < squares.length; k++)
{
    squareIndex = squares[k].indexOf(squareId);


    if (squareIndex > -1) {
        numberIndex = squareIndex;
        squareIndex = k;
        break
    }
}

    alert('NumberIndex: '+ numberIndex+' ParentSquareIndex: '+ squareIndex);
});
```

Comment: This example is using jQuery, but the principle should be the same regardless.

Comment: You can't set squareIndex = k? :)

Comment: No, because I don't get the square's index position in the array.

Comment: Oh i thought you wanted the index of the square, not the number itself, lets have a look

Comment: But your answer was correct, I just removed squareIndex = k; :)

Answer (score 0):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/aldjCQRchgESR7IWn367?p=preview i hope that will help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.22/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.22"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello !</p>
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="lines in squares track by $index ">
        <td ng-repeat="nr in lines track by $index" ng-click="getMyId(nr)">{{nr}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';

  var squares = [];
            for(var i = 0; i <= 8; i++)
            {
                squares[i] = [];
                for(var j = (i * 20) + 1; j <= 20 * i + 20; j++)
                {
                    if (squares[i] === null)
                    {
                        squares[i] = ''+j;  
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        squares[i].push('' + j);
                    }
                }
            }
          $scope.squares = squares;

          $scope.getMyId = function(id){

            alert(id);

          }
            console.log(squares);
});
```